# c# visual studio and lapack

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, lapack

Is there a way to call LAPACK routines inside a `stored procedure` in `C#` `(visual studio 2008`)?.

If so, How would be the steps?.

Comment: From within a SQL Stored Procedure - or within a C# method?

Comment: well, I would like to comunicate SQL with C# and use LAPACK library, I would like to be in SQL stored procedure.

Comment: Are you able to use LAPACK from within C# already, and just need guidance to incorporating that into SQL (SQL Server I hope!).

Comment: well, If you could reference to some tutorial (incorporing Lapack and SQL) I would be very happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compile LAPACK into a .dll and then call it from C#. I don't know how SQL will fit in this, but I think that is a separate question.

In detail look at http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-for-windows/lapack/ and in the end there are instructions on how to compile the sources. I make a static library for BLAS and a dynamic library for LAPACK. Then depending on which procedures you want to use, you will have to write managed wrapper functions that call the `.dll`.